# Bootstrap: Buttons in a row with no gap between

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to this. I'm trying to make a row of buttons in Bootstrap with no gap in between, but trying to adjust margin and padding settings makes no difference, so I think it's something else.
[image]

```
<div class="row text-center">
  <div class="col-xs-2">
    <button class="btn"><a href="x"><i class="fa fa-github fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-2">
    <button class="btn"><a href="y"><i class="fa fa-youtube-play fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-2">
    <button class="btn"><a href="z"><i class="fa fa-stack-exchange fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-2">
    <button class="btn"><a href="x"><i class="fa fa-quora fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-2">
    <button class="btn"><a href="y"><i class="fa fa-reddit-alien fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-2">
    <button class="btn"><a href="z"><i class="fa fa-free-code-camp fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Of course the buttons have space in between since you divided horizontal space into six columns, each containing a button. Put the buttons inside one column and there will be no gaps. Unless you want them to take up the whole width of every column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gaps are shown because you put each button inside each `col-xs-2`. The `col` in bootstrap has its own width. To solve your issue, try to create just 1 column and call it `col-xs-12` and put all your buttons there.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row text-center">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
     <button class="btn"><a href="x"><i class="fa fa-github fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></button>
     <button class="btn"><a href="x"><i class="fa fa-github fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></button>
     <button class="btn"><a href="x"><i class="fa fa-github fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></button>
     <button class="btn"><a href="x"><i class="fa fa-github fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></button>
     <button class="btn"><a href="x"><i class="fa fa-github fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Bro please provide CSS for every id's and classes so that we can get idea.

Or you can put your all buttons in single col-md-12 like

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
Add buttons
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: 12 columns is 100% width in bootstrap, so it looks identical to just omitting the row and column completely